# prefix and suffix of symbol in shared library

Tags: c, dll, linker, shared-libraries

I was using dlopen to load load libtest_main.so and got a dlopen error: **undefined symbol: _Z6launchv** and then used nm to lis the symbols like:
**U _Z6launchv**
The function launch() is called in libtest_main.so and located in another shared library libhost.so which is added by "-lhost" and is listed by nm:
**T launch**
So, the prefix "_Z6" and suffix "v" are the reason for the issue? What does they mean?
Any comments are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: That's name mangling. Was `launch` compiled as C++, without an `extern "C"`?

Comment: thank Thomas， After putting the launch into extern ”c" and recompiling the libhost.so,  the issue is gone.  the GCC has always compiled files with C extension as C?